# iOS: UIView hierarchy: make Map View active under UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mkmapview, core-graphics

I have simple UIView hierarchy:

```
container View:
→ Map View
→ Custom View
```

My custom view partially overlaps the Map View. I can see a map, but I can't interact with the map e.g. zoom, scroll etc.

How can I archive partially map overlap and interaction in the same time?
Feel free to ask me if you didn't understand something.

EDIT

I want to disable black areas to interaction, but allow interaction in the circle i.e. in the center of my UIView with black overlay areas.

[image]

Comment: What is the frame of mapview and customview with respect to continer view?

Comment: apply a mask to your customview

Comment: @Apurv it's same as a container view bounds

Comment: @Daij-Djan how can I make this? Can you show an example or a link?

Comment: I do the exact same thing btw. I mask my custom view to get the map to interact. I added a reduced example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have something like this:

[image: example]

You want to be able to touch the red area, and touch the map where the yellow area is, but it is being blocked by the yellow subview?

If so, subclass the yellow subview and override the -pointInside: method, which allows you to specify whether a touched point will collide with the view, or fall back to a view behind it.

```
- (BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds] containsPoint:point];
}
```

Comment: I only want to interact with red area. I'll try to implement this.

Comment: Wow, this work like a charm, but I don't understand why we make such rect, why this numbers? And why they work:)

Comment: @flinth my numbers are just an example, which will only allow interaction in a 100x30 square. You should change the code around to best suit your touch region.

Comment: for simple forms this is good. but masking is better once the form gets more complex IMO

Comment: simple forms include everything that can EASILY be expressed as a bezierpath

Comment: @SomeGuy all works nice except that `view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` doesn't work. I tried set it in storyboard, in init method of uiview subclass, in my view controller viewDidLoad method :(

Comment: @flinth don't worry about the userInteractionEnabled = NO part, that's if you didn't want interaction at all on the overlay view

Comment: @SomeGuy but I don't want to interact with map (let's see the image) on yellow area, but I want on the red one.

Comment: @SomeGuy today I'm continue to investigate this problem and I found, that if I set a CGRect in `- (BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` we can touch a whole rectangle, not a circle, I my case I want to make active circle only.

Comment: @flinth I've updated my answer to show how to do it with a circle like in your world map image example, the code should go in the black subclassed UIView

Comment: @SomeGuy I've found this answer right now parallel with you haha:) then, opened SO and you update your answer with same solution:) Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

if the view only partly covers the view below it, apply a mask to tell IOS that

e.g. from my github fork of XBPageCurl

```
- (void)applyCornerMaskAsNeeded {
    //
    //create mask
    //

    UIImage *cornerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"corner_view_mask.png"]; //this is black//white/alpha
    CGRect b = self.layer.bounds;
    CGRect rtCornerRect=CGRectZero;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(b.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //white bg
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, b);

    //draw corner image mask
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, cornerImage.size.height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    rtCornerRect = [self cornerRectFor:XBPageDragViewCornerTopRight withSize:cornerImage.size.width];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rtCornerRect, cornerImage.CGImage);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //   
    //apply mask
    //
    CALayer *l = [CALayer layer];
    l.frame = b;
    l.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
    l.name = @"XBPageDragViewCornersMask";
    [self.layer setMask:l];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

}
```

another example  is in the apple docs but this should already be pretty clear:

1. you draw mask. black, alpha
2. you apple the mask to your view's layer
3. done

Comment: Masking to simply prevent user interaction in certain areas seems a bit overkill to me

Comment: @SomeGuy well if it is a simple 'rectange' (or other simple form) then pointInside is maybe better but if you have more... complex partitial overlay Id say masks are better

Comment: they are basically worry free :D

Comment: For a rounded corners interaction mask, check out UIBezierPath, which also contains a -pointInside: method that can be used with the UIView -pointInside: